# Convert bunch of string to array and compare two arrays to get common values in both

Tags: arrays, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-5

This is my code -
   Here I'm trying to get all the constants which has feature_toggle string attached to it, by searching through all the files using a regex, which has been cloned from the git and stored locally, for example,

```
feature_enabled?(TEST_ONE) 
feature_enabled?(TEST_TWO)
feature_enabled?(TEST_THREE)
feature_enabled?(TEST_FOUR)
feature_enabled?(KEY_AS_PRIMARY)
```

From this I'll be getting following values in *matches_found*

```
 ["TEST_ONE", "TEST_TWO", "TEST_THREE","TEST_FOUR","KEY_AS_PRIMARY"]
```

This is the method where I'm trying to achieve that.

```
    # public: retrieve the constant feature names based on the asset passed
    #
    # filename - path of each file under a repository for running the scan for example - /Users/sagarPC/Desktop/project/tmp/icdev/somefolder/app/models/project_one/orion/add_me_task.rb
    # pattern - regex pattern which search for the names.Ex- /(?:\.|!)?feature_enabled\?\((.*?)\)/m
    #
    # Ex - feature_enabled?(TEST_ONE)
    #
    # returns each constant's value in an array
    # Ex - [testone,testtwo,testthree,testfour]

    def self.constant_discovery(file_name, pattern) 
    matches = File.open(file_name).read.scan(pattern).uniq.flatten.compact
    matches_found = matches.map {|key| key.split(',')[0].scan(/^[A-Z]+(?:_[A-Z]+)*$/)}.flatten
    search_pattern = /([A-Z]+_)*[A-Z]+ = '.+'/
    File.open(file_name) do |f|
    lines = f.find_all {|line| line =~ search_pattern }
      lines.each do |line|
        if line.include?('=')
          print line unless line.empty?
         required_output = matches_found & line
        end 
       line
      end
     end
     matches 
    end
```

By the above code I'm getting *matches_found* values like below,

```
["TEST_ONE", "TEST_TWO", "TEST_THREE","TEST_FOUR","KEY_AS_PRIMARY"]
```

Where as, *line* is producing output like this,

```
TEST_ONE = 'testone'
TEST_TWO = 'testtwo'
TEST_THREE = 'testthree'
TEST_FOUR = 'testfour'
```

These constants can be declared somewhere in the cloned repository and can be used used somewhere else.
In the *require_output* I need to get the common constants values between *matches_found* and *line*, from those common constants return only those which are declared somewhere and has values assigned to it. The value of the constant can be declared anywhere in the cloned repo.

When I tried to do this I'm facing issue while comparing *matches_found* and *line* with error message saying "failed with error no implicit conversion of String into Array "

By this I understood that I have to convert values of *line* to an array. And then should compare it with *matches_found*, after this I'll be getting common constant from both the arrays in *required_output*. And later I can get those values which has been assigned to those common constants.
In the end, the method should produce following return values,

```
[testone,testtwo,testthree,testfour]
```

As I'm very new to ruby can someone please help me with it?
Sorry for pasting my whole method. Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: can you give an example of the inputs you're passing to your method?

Comment: You are expecting readers to reverse-engineer your code to figure out what you are attempting to do. That's both ineffective and a waste of our time. Please edit your question to begin by explaining what you are attempting to do, in words, with at least one example for illustration. Whenever you give an example be sure to include the desired result. Then present your code and the errors or incorrect results you have obtained.

Comment: sorry about that, I guess now you can figure out what the method does.

Comment: @lacostenycoder Please help me out

Comment: @sagark you have not provided a single example of how you would call the method and with what arguments.  We cannot help you with that. All of your wordy description could be replace by a simple example.